# Non-strict by-name arguments in Python?

Tags: python, parser-combinators, callbyname, evaluation-strategy

**Question**

Is there any way to declare function arguments as non-strict (passed [by-name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_name))?

If this is not possible directly: are there any helper functions or decorators that help me achieve something similar?

---

**Concrete example**

Here is a littly toy-example to experiment with.

Suppose that I want to build a tiny parser-combinator library that can cope with the following classic grammar for arithmetic expressions with parentheses (numbers replaced by a single literal value `1` for simplicity):

```
num    = "1"

factor = num 
       | "(" + expr + ")"

term   = factor + "*" + term 
       | factor

expr   = term + "+" + expr
       | term
```

Suppose that I define a *parser combinator* as an object that has a method `parse` that can take list of tokens, current position, and either throw a parse error, or return a result and a new position. I can nicely define a `ParserCombinator` base class that provides `+` (concatenation) and `|` (alternative). Then I can define parser combinators that accept constant strings, and implement `+` and `|`:

```
# Two kinds of errors that can be thrown by a parser combinator
class UnexpectedEndOfInput(Exception): pass
class ParseError(Exception): pass

# Base class that provides methods for `+` and `|` syntax
class ParserCombinator:
  def __add__(self, next):
    return AddCombinator(self, next)
  def __or__(self, other):
    return OrCombinator(self, other)

# Literally taken string constants
class Lit(ParserCombinator):
  def __init__(self, string):
    self.string = string

  def parse(self, tokens, pos):
    if pos < len(tokens):
      t = tokens[pos]
      if t == self.string:
        return t, (pos + 1)
      else:
        raise ParseError
    else:
      raise UnexpectedEndOfInput

def lit(str): 
  return Lit(str)

# Concatenation
class AddCombinator(ParserCombinator):
  def __init__(self, first, second):
    self.first = first
    self.second = second
  def parse(self, tokens, pos):
    x, p1 = self.first.parse(tokens, pos)
    y, p2 = self.second.parse(tokens, p1)
    return (x, y), p2

# Alternative
class OrCombinator(ParserCombinator):
  def __init__(self, first, second):
    self.first = first
    self.second = second
  def parse(self, tokens, pos):
    try:
      return self.first.parse(tokens, pos)
    except:
      return self.second.parse(tokens, pos)
```

So far, everything is fine. However, because the non-terminal symbols of the grammar are defined in a mutually recursive fashion, and I cannot eagerly unfold the tree of all possible parser combinations, I have to work with *factories* of parser combinators, and wrap them into something like this:

```
# Wrapper that prevents immediate stack overflow
class LazyParserCombinator(ParserCombinator):
  def __init__(self, parserFactory):
    self.parserFactory = parserFactory
  def parse(self, tokens, pos):
    return self.parserFactory().parse(tokens, pos)

def p(parserFactory):
  return LazyParserCombinator(parserFactory)
```

This indeed allows me to write down the grammar in a way that is very close to the EBNF:

```
num    = p(lambda: lit("1"))
factor = p(lambda: num | (lit("(") + expr + lit(")")))
term   = p(lambda: (factor + lit("*") + term) | factor)
expr   = p(lambda: (term + lit("+") + expr) | term)
```

And it actually works:

```
tokens = [str(x) for x in "1+(1+1)*(1+1+1)+1*(1+1)"]
print(expr.parse(tokens, 0))
```

However, the `p(lambda: ...)` in every line is a bit annoying. Is there some idiomatic way to get rid of it? It would be nice if one could somehow pass the whole RHS of a rule "by-name", without triggering the eager evaluation of the infinite mutual recursion.

---

**What I've tried**

I've checked what's available in the core language: it seems that only `if`, `and` and `or` can "short-circuit", please correct me if I'm wrong.

I've tried looking at how other non-toy-example libraries do this.

- For example, 
  [funcparserlib](https://github.com/vlasovskikh/funcparserlib) 
  uses explicit forward declarations to avoid mutual recursion 
  (look at the `forward_decl` and `value.define` 
   part in github README.md example code).
- The `parsec.py` uses some special `@generate` decorators 
  and seems to do something like monadic parsing using coroutines.
  That's all very nice, but my goal is to understand what options 
  I have with regards to the basic evaluation strategies available 
  in Python.

I've also found something like the [`lazy_object_proxy.Proxy`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lazy-object-proxy), but it didn't seem to help to instantiate such objects in more concise way.

So, is there a nicer way to pass arguments by-name and avoid the blowup of mutually recursively defined values?

Comment: It looks to me like your operations will be evaluated right-to-left. As long as you stick to multiplication and addition, that's not a problem. But once you include subtraction and division, you'll find that "2 - 3 + 4" evaluates very differently right-to-left from the correct left-to-right. Pyparsing (which I am the author) is another Python parser combinator library you might take a look at - pyparsing also uses an explicit Forward() class for a recursive grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a nice idea, but it's not something that Python's syntax allows for: Python expressions are always evaluated strictly (with the exception of `if` blocks and `and` and `or` short-circuiting expressions).

In particular, the problem is that in an expression like:

```
num = p(lit("1"))
```

The `p` function argument is always received with a new name binding to the same object. The object resulting from evaluating `lit("1")` is not *named* anything (until a name is created by the formal parameter to `p`), so there is no name there to bind to. Conversely, there must be an object there, or otherwise `p` wouldn't be able to receive a value at all.

What you could do is add a new object to use instead of a lambda to defer evaluation of a name. For example, something like:

```
class DeferredNamespace(object):
    def __init__(self, namespace):
        self.__namespace = namespace
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return DeferredLookup(self.__namespace, name)

class DeferredLookup(object):
    def __init__(self, namespace, name):
        self.__namespace = namespace
        self.__name = name
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(getattr(self.__namespace, self.__name), name)

d = DeferredNamespace(locals())

num = p(d.lit("1"))
```

In this case, `d.lit` actually doesn't return `lit`, it returns a `DeferredLookup` object that will use `getattr(locals(), 'lit')` to resolve its members when they are actually used. Note that this captures `locals()` eagerly, which you might not want; you can adapt that to use a lambda, or better yet just create all your entities in some other namespace anyway.

You still get the wart of the `d.` in the syntax, which may or may not be a deal-breaker, depending on your goals with this API.

Comment: Sorry for the probably dumb follow-up question, but: `__getattr__` is the special method that modifies how member access `x.y` works, but `__namespace` is not special, it's just a variable name you came up with, correct? Overriding `__getattr__` to defer evaluation until the `parse` method is accessed is definitely a very interesting idea, I must think about it a little bit. In the languages I've programmed previously, there was no direct correspondence of `__getattr__`, so I currently don't even know when I should *want* to use it :] Thanks for the interesting proposal, I will try it.

Comment: Yes, `__name` and `__namespace` are my own variable names. (Names starting with a double-underscore but not ending with one are typically user-defined private members; names that begin and end with a double-underscore are reserved by the language.) You might want to read the Python documentation on `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__` -- for example, `__getattr__` will not get called for members that already exist on `DeferredLookup` objects, like `__str__`, but you might want to forward some of those to the deferred target instead.

Comment: Accepted this answer because it extends the toolbox in a non-obvious way. For the particular example of parser combinators, I've ended up using a combination of decorators and a lazy parser class. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

**Special solution for functions that must accept exactly *one* by-name argument**

> If you want to define a function `f` that has to take one single argument by-name, consider making `f` into a `@decorator`. Instead of an argument littered with `lambdas`, the decorator can then directly receive the function definition.

---

The `lambdas` in the question appear because we need a way to make the execution of the right hand sides lazy. However, if we change the definitions of non-terminal symbols to be `def`s rather than local variables, the RHS is also not executed immediately. Then what we have to do is to convert these `def`s into `ParserCombinator`s somehow. For this, we can use decorators.

---

We can define a decorator that wraps a function into a `LazyParserCombinator` as follows:

```
def rule(f):
  return LazyParserCombinator(f)
```

and then apply it to the *functions* that hold the definitions of each grammar rule:

```
@rule 
def num():    return lit("1")

@rule 
def factor(): return num | (lit("(") + expr + lit(")"))

@rule 
def term():   return factor + lit("*") + term | factor

@rule 
def expr():   return (term + lit("+") + expr) | term
```

The syntactic overhead within the right hand sides of the rules is minimal (no overhead for referencing other rules, no `p(...)`-wrappers or `ruleName()`-parentheses needed), and there is no counter-intuitive boilerplate with lambdas.

---

Explanation:

Given a higher order function `h`, we can use it to *decorate* other function `f` as follows:

```
@h
def f():
  <body>
```

What this does is essentially:

```
def f():
  <body>

f = h(f)
```

and `h` is not constrained to returning functions, it can also return other objects, like `ParserCombinator`s above.

Comment: I would be thankful if someone could comment whether this considered good practice. By [this definition](https://hynek.me/articles/decorators/), the decorator is just "broken". Or is it OK if I do it "intentionally"?